# Change default title in Magento

Tags: magento

I follow: `System -> Configuration -> Design -> HTML Head -> Default Title`, and change title to: `This is title for my website`.

But when visit home page, title is: `Home page`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Please refresh the cache and then check

Answer (score 3):

Home page is managed from ,it cms home page.Please goto admin >CMS>page> find here home page.and  here you change title

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [**thread**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/231035/)

**Step 1:** Goto Home page in the CMS page editor

**Step 2:** click on design, then enter this XML into the “Layout Update XML” field:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setData"><key>title</key><value>Home</value></action>
</reference>
```

Now the home page title is set as `Home`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Go to CMS->Page in Admin section
in the list that shows up see the left most 'Title' column. You should find a page with the title 'Home page'. Note that this is the page title you are seeing when you visit the homepage.
Click that row
Under Page Information you will see Page Title. Changing that will change the title of your homepage.